# SAPUI5 JSONModel extended as singleton instance

Tags: singleton, sapui5

I'd like to know if is possible to create a JSONModel extended and make it as singleton instance.

I've already created my extended JSONModel but I need to use it in different parts of my app.

How to turn the constructor of my model private and create the getInstance method?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to access your model from anywhere, you don't necessarily need to create a singleton. You could for example create the model instance and assign them to the UI5 Core.

```js
// Where you create your model
var oModel = new CustomModel();
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);

// To access the model from anywhere
var oModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel();
```

If you insist on having a singleton, you could simply remove the constructor once the instance has been created:

```js
(function() {
    "use strict";
    var oInstance;
    sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.extend("CustomModel", {
        constructor : function() {
            sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.apply(this, arguments);
            if (oInstance) {
                throw "Constructor of singleton cannot be called"
            }
        }
    });
    CustomModel.getInstance = function() {
        if (!oInstance) {
            oInstance = new CustomModel();
            oInstance.constructor = null
        }
        return oInstance;
    };
}());
```

That's just from the top of my head so there might by typos in there.

On a side note, I would highly recommend reading [What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons) and instead of using them, rather inject the model to your dependencies.

Comment: Highlighting why singletons are a bad design pattern is the best part about your answer! ;-)